# calling shell script from python where shell connects to database

Tags: python, bash, shell, db2

I want to call shell script from python code. The shell script which I am trying to call is having multiple database (DB2) call in it; means it connects to DB2 database multiple times and execute different database sqls. I tried using subprocess.call method like (`subprocess.call(['./<shell script with full path>'])`); but it seems before the script connects to database and executes the commands mentioned within the script, it is terminating. But when I am calling the shell script as a standalone script from command line, then it is working good.

Is there any other way this can be handled?

Comment: You are using a relative path (contains . ) , how are you guaranteeing that $PWD is correct?  Next, does the shell script correctly dot in the db2profile?  Do Some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

> subprocess: The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes,
>   connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return
>   codes.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Usage:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
process.wait()
print process.returncode
```

Side note: It is best practice to avoid using shell=True as it is a security hazard.

[Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)